# Frequency of vibration of rod

Tags: vibrations

Imagine you have got a metal rod of length $l$ and the left side of the rod is fixed, and the rod is pointing in the direction of the x-axis of an imagined coordinate system. At distance $d$ from the left side a nonuniform mass is spinning - think of an unbalanced motor. So this unbalanced mass produces a force in the y-axis (ignoring the x-component for this question) on the rod of the form $F(t)=K_0 \cos(\omega_0 t)$.  At distance $d_2$ from the left end of the rod a spring-mass-dashpot (effectively a damped oscillator) is connected to the rod pointing in the y-direction.

**My question: What can we say about $\omega$ - the frequency at which the damped oscillator can oscillate? Is it possible that $\omega < \omega_0$ or $\omega > \omega_0$ or does it have to be that $\omega = \omega_0$, which would be the case if the damped oscillator was driven directly.**

My approach:
The rod has many normal modes and this force probably will excite some of them. (Thinking of a tuning fork or piano string or knocking on a metal handrail). So I think all three cases mentioned above should be true..